# android can android:gravity do this?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Searched all day and came up with a poor solution i think.
i want three  ImageButton placed on the right sida of the screen.
Not centered but just above center position..

With the code below i get the result i want but,
If the user have a bigger screen they will not have this position right?

I have tried the `android:gravity`all day and all i can do with it is
to center the three buttons very nicely.

What should i use to make the three buttons always stay at the positions that 
they are on the image belove.
i have the button image in 3 different sizes in hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi folder.

```
      <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rightRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_A" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:text="A"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            /> 
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_B" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="B"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_A"
            />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_C" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="C"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_B"

            />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Picture of the three buttons placed on the right side, and my daughter of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android Can i use layout_weight to position RelativeLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428747/android-can-i-use-layout-weight-to-position-relativelayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to put all three buttons within a LinearLayout (for simplicity's sake) and then set the layout of this container programmatically.

You can see the size of the screen using `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPizels` and then set the top margin accordingly.

Comment: I know howto use the rightRelativeLayout.addView. To add dynamically created views but Question is should i now use the rightRelativeLayout.layout(l, t, r, b). Im not adding a view only change the layout height. l=left, t=top, r=right .

Comment: @Erik You aren't changing the layout height. All you need to do is change the top margin, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout, and then use the following properties on the LinearLayout:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

EDIT: Ok, I've done some testing and found a way of doing what you want without the use of styling it programatically, here's the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rightRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dip"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_A" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        /> 
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_B" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_C" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, then your best bet is to do what Zack has said and set the margin programatically.

Comment: i think that is almost what i already have. The android:layout_marginBottom="80dip" will be a problem if the app run on a bigger screen. I need a procentage calculation that puts the row of buttons always at the same location no matter what size of the screen