# Can I use layout_weight to position a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying all day to get this to work and i think that I can use `RelativeLayout`

```
android:layout_weight="0.3"
```

to place three buttons on the right side of the screen, not centered but 30% down from the top.

Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

The following is my XML that shows three buttons underneath each other but in top right position:

```
   </RelativeLayout>
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_A" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"


            /> 
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_B" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="B"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_A"
            />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_C" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="C"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_B"

            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[UPDATE] Added final working version for people who need it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/examplegallery" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_newpen_drawtext" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pen"
    />      
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/etx_addtext_drawtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete_pen"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_newpen_drawtext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
    />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete_pen" 
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_save_drawtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Del"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_save_drawtext" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save"
        />

   </RelativeLayout>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rightLinerLayoutL0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp" 
                  android:id="@+id/rightLinerLayoutL1" 
                  android:layout_weight="0.15" 
                  android:layout_width="0dp">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp" 
                  android:orientation="vertical" 
                  android:id="@+id/rightLinerLayoutL2" 
                  android:layout_weight="0.85" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton android:text="Button_A" 
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/btn_A" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:src="@drawable/drawer"
            android:onClick="btnAListener">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:text="Button_B" 
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_B" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:src="@drawable/drawer"
            android:onClick="btnBListener">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:text="Button_C" 
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_C" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:src="@drawable/drawer"
            android:onClick="btnCListener">
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i've updated my answer to fill in the example i promised :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack 2 LinearLayout (L1, L2) sections with weights of 0.3 and 0.7 (and heights of 0dp) inside a LinearLayout (L0) with vertical orientation and total weight of 1.0. Put your buttons in the 0.7 weighted layout (L2). That will give you your spacing of 30% above the buttons.

You can then place the containing LinearLayout (L0) inside a RelativeLayout (R0) and place L0 relative to the right of the parent (R0), which will position the entire thing on the right side of the screen.

Edit: My version is pretty much same as Milde in end, except using a root of `RelativeLayout` so I could put the `layout_alignParentRight="true"` to ensure it's flush to the right. The only sticking point I found was ensuring your first LinearLayout has height of `fill_parent` so that your spacer really is 30% of screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:weightSum="1.0" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.7" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button android:text="Button 1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:text="Button 2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:text="Button 3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @markf I updated my question with your suggested code implementation . When you have time please comment. I think there's a small error somewhere because nothing is showed on the screen

Comment: @Erik look at my answer (I didnt use Relative Layout), but mark markf as correct... I just posted some code

Comment: @markf thanks for the help. It's working very nicely. Im marking your answer as the right one. Down below you say: "(try colouring your backgrounds of each), better to use RelativeLayout to flush it right". I have png images with background transparent. And what is "flush"

Comment: @Erik Thanks! "flush" simply means "pushed up against". And the comment about coloured backgrounds was only for when you're trying to get the layout right and can't see why it's not working. It helps see if your widths and gravity settings are OK. Remove them when you're happy with layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rightLinerLayoutL0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightLinerLayoutL1" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/rightLinerLayoutL2" android:layout_weight="0.7" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:text="Button_A" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_A" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button_B" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_B" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button_C" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_C" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout >
```

[image]

Comment: @Milde your code is working perfect and I can adjust the Y position with the layout_weight to. Thanks again

Comment: @Erik no problem, but as I mentioned in my EDIT above, it doesn't seem to be "real" 30%/70%. It's more like 20/80 because LL1 is shrinking when you insert Buttons in LL2... dunno why.

Comment: @Milka anyway I think it's working for now so i can move on. Will wait for a second opinion from @markf. i dont have a larger device to test this on so it has to work

Comment: @Erik got it - remove layout_height of LL1 and LL2 :-) looks better now. I've updated the answer.

Comment: the updated Code above gives me no error, maybe try to set them to 0px instead of removing the attributes

Comment: A tip when using layouts is to set the `android:background` to something different for each layout object (i use #111, #333, #555, ... etc), it makes visualising them much easier.

Comment: @Milde try to adjust your widths as they are filling the entire screen (try colouring your backgrounds of each), better to use RelativeLayout to flush it right, and only set widths on things you need to set. The `fill_parent` on L1 would be better as `0dp`, and the `fill_parent` on L2 would be better as `wrap_content`, otherwise you converted my description into an example perfectly :)

Comment: They actually both have to be set to 0 size for the sizes to be completely determined by the weights. This is because the weights only  are used to allocate extra space after the sizes are subtracted from the total.

Answer (score 0):

Since this xml file doesn't give error it doesn't mean that you can use these attributes (weight, orientation associated to LinearLayout) with RelativeLayout. Please see the documentation for RelativeLayout first.

Comment: it'actually a LinearLayout, just forgot to change it back after some testing.