# RelativeLayout and height percentage. Unable to use layout_below and layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with relativelayout where its children could use layout_below and layout_weight to set its percentage height.

For example, we have a relative layout and inside of it we have three linear layouts with textviews. Now, I would like to set for three of them (linearlayouts) 25,50,25 % of height of total height of relative layout. How could I accomplish it?

I found a solution for [weight_sum and and relativelayout (CLICK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428747/android-can-i-use-layout-weight-to-position-relativelayout), but it doesn't use layout_below.

How can I fix this?

I tried to add additional linearlayout inside of all linearlayouts, but then I am unable use layout_below.

Here is concept picture idea:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linlay_leftcol_notification_header" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay_leftcol_clock_theday"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_theday"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/theday"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay_leftcol_clock_thetime"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linlay_leftcol_clock_theday" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_thetime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thetime"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay_leftcol_clock_thenumber_themonth_theyear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linlay_leftcol_clock_thetime" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_thenumberofday_themonth_theyear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thenumberofday_themonth_theyear"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Hello 1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Hello 2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Hello 3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you look closely I have kept weights of inner 3 layouts as 1, 2 and 1 (in order) to keep the desired output i.e. 1st layout will take 25% of the display height, 2nd will take 50% and 3rd will take remaining 25%. Works very well for me.

Comment: After trying it out if you are satisfied with this answer then may be you would like to undo your '-1' :-)

Comment: so the tldr; is: children inherit parent special params like LinearLayout -> layout_weight.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#A52A2A" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_theday"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1st layout"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#8B008B" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_theday"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2ndlayout"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00008B" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3rd layout"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_side"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_theday"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="side layout"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use either weight or relative layout properties. You can make that 25,50,25 like this...you align the parent left first textview, align parent right, other textview, and the remaining textview's you align to the left of the first one and to the right of the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use Table Layout and inside that, you put your textviews. There is an  attribute, "stretch column", for table layout. There you can mention the size as " 0,2,1" like that...